# how to call firebase inside the .nextjs getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to get 'sample' document in Firestore using getServerSideProps , I want to get my **blog post** with matching url. Code below doesn't work. It's result is 'can't read' What should I do? or is there the other way?

```
export async function getServerSideProps({params}) {

    let {slagUrl} = params;
    
    const article = [];

    const articleRef = collection(db, "BlogArticles");
    const q = query(articleRef, where("slug", "==", slagUrl));
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        const articles = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
        }));
        console.log('query',articles[0])
        article.push(articles[0]);
    });

    return {
        props: { article }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the full error that you see?

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: You are probably returning before the snapshot query gets completed?